# Confusion on statement of Fubini's theorem for characteristic function of measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having trouble understanding what this theorem is saying.

**Theorem**.  Let $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \lambda)$ be a complete measure space and suppose $E \in \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$.  Then:

1. $E_{x} \in \tau$ a.e. d$\mu(x)$
2. $f: X \to [0, \infty]$, $f(x) = \nu(E_{x})$ (a.e. d$\mu(x)$) defines a measurable function.
3. $\lambda(E) = \int \limits_{X} \nu(E_{x}) \text{ d}\mu$.

Note that this product measure space is the product of complete measure spaces $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$.  Also, $E_{x} = \{ y \in Y \mid (x, y) \in E \}$.

My points of confusion:

The only statement in this theorem I understand completely is statement 3.  It is saying that the integral of the characteristic function of $E$ with respect to $\lambda$ is actually an iterated integral.  But for 1, is it saying that for almost all $x$, $E_{x} \in \tau$?  Which means there are some $x$ such that $E_{x} \not \in \tau$?  If so, then that means the function defined in 2 is only defined almost everywhere.  What does it mean for a function that is only defined almost everywhere to be measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $x$ such that $E_{x} \not \in \tau$ you can define $f(x)$ to be anything you want. Now you have a function that is defined everywhere. Apply the usual measurability definition. Notice the measure space is **complete**: any subset of a zero measure set is measurable.

Comment: So really I should amend 2 to say the function equals a measurable function almost everywhere?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you made the extra note on completeness.  Can you please expand on why completeness is significant?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Completeness is relevant because allows you to define $f$ arbitrarily on sets of measure zero. Without it, you can not guarantee the $f$ you end up is measurable.

Comment: One of the statements I was unable to prove is that defining a function arbitrarily on a set of measure 0 still gives a measurable function in a complete measure space.  Is the proof short/easy?  I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I got it!  Ok, I understand now.  The proof is as follows:  Suppose $f$ is measurable, and change $f$ to an arbitrary function $h$ on a set $N$ of measure $0$ (in a complete measure space).  Call this new function $g$.  Then $\{ x \mid g > \alpha \} = [\{ x \mid f > \alpha \} \cap (X \setminus N)] \cup [\{ x \mid h(x) > \alpha \} \cap N]$, and the key here is that $[\{ x \mid h(x) > \alpha \} \cap N]$ is a subset of $N$ which has measure $0$, which means it is measurable, too, and so is $\{ x \mid g > \alpha \}$.  Thanks!

Comment: you could amend 2 but I prefer to not think in terms of functions $f$ but rather in terms of equivalence classes of functions $[f]=\{g : g=f\, a.e\}$.

Comment: The problem I have with thinking about these as equivalence classes is that the function $f$ defined above does not have the same domain as the functions defined on all of $X$.  It is not defined for some $x$, and so it wouldn't really be in any equivalence classes.  The functions in an equivalence class all have the same domain, right?

Comment: Yes they have the same domain $X$, not $X\times Y$.

Comment: They don't have the same domain, though.  One of the functions is not defined for all $x$, so its domain is strictly smaller.

Comment: You misunderstood my point: do not think $f$ as a function with a smaller domain but think of f in 2 as **the equivalence class** itself. Analogy, the elements of an $L^1$ space are not functions but equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: But your comment got me thinking about equality almost everywhere of functions with different domains.  It does come up.  I asked a question about it just now here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879057/sequence-of-measurable-functions-converging-a-e-to-a-measurable-function