# Sequence of measurable functions converging a.e. to a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I understand if $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space, and we have a sequence of measurable functions $f_{n}$ such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ exists almost everywhere d$\mu$ (a.e. d$\mu$), then it's equal to a measurable function almost everywhere.  The way this is constructed is to first call the set where the limit doesn't exist $N$ (and this clearly has measure $0$).  Then, we:

Define a new sequence 
$$\tilde{f_{n}} = \begin{cases} f_{n}(x) & x \not \in N \\
0 & x \in N \end{cases}$$

and we can think of $\tilde{f_{n}}$ as $f_{n} - f_{n}\chi_{N}$, where $\chi_{N}$ is the characteristic function of the set $N$.  Clearly, $\tilde{f_{n}}$ is measurable since it is the sum of measurable functions.  And so the limit of the sequence $\{ \tilde{f_{n}} \}$ is defined everywhere and measurable.  Specifically,
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \tilde{f_{n}} = \begin{cases} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n} & x \not \in N \\ 0 & x \in N. \end{cases} $$

So we have a measurable function which is equal to $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ except on $N$.  But my question is:

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ is only defined on $X \setminus N$, which means its domain is $X \setminus N$.  Why do we say this is equal to $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \tilde{f_{n}}$ almost everywhere if they have different domains?  Does it make sense to talk about them not being equal on $N$ if one of them isn't even defined on $N$?

**I guess my question is:  If $X \subseteq X'$, and $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X' \to Y$, suppose $f = g$ on $X$ (with $X' \setminus X$ having measure $0$).  Does the statement $f = g$ a.e. even make sense?  We can't compare then on $X' \setminus X$ to say they aren't equal on it because one of the functions isn't even defined on that set.**

**Another question that has been spawned from this question is whether it makes sense to integrate a function over a set that is not in its domain.**

Comment: A lot of notation gets abused in measure theory. That said, $f=g$ a.e. does make sense, as you can expand it to: $(\exists N \in \Sigma) \, [ \mu(N) = 0 \land (\forall x \in X' \setminus N) \, f(x) = g(x)]$. This definition never "calls $f$ with an invalid argument".

Comment: So it is not correct to state "$f$ does not equal $g$ on a set of measure 0"?  And we *can* say that two functions with different domains are equal almost everywhere?

Comment: As for the first point, I think technically yes, but analysts don't really care about distinctions that fine. As for the second point, yes, I think so, because I think the expansion I wrote above is a valid definition for "$f=g$ a.e.".

Comment: Ian is right on the money.

Comment: @Ian I understand your point and the definition you put.  But I don't know how to apply it to this scenario:  If $f$ is defined on $X \setminus N$ where $N$ has measure 0, and $g$ is defined on $X$, and $f = g$ on $X \setminus N$, then clearly by your definition, $f = g$ a.e. -- but does that mean $f$ is in the equivalence class of $g$?  They don't have the same domain, so asking for $\int \limits_{X} |f - g| \text{ d}\mu = 0$ doesn't make sense since the integral doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think the equivalence relation used to construct the $L^p$ spaces is only defined on pairs with the same domain. That said, again, analysts don't actually care that much about this distinction, and are happy to abbreviate "any extension of $f$ to all of $X$ is measurable and equivalent to $g$" to "$f=g$ a.e.". All this said, it actually frustrates me that we even operate so much at the level of measurable functions themselves. There is a topology of a.e. convergence, with which the set of equivalence classes can be equipped. This topological space is really the object under study.

Comment: Is it bad that this lack of "rigor" bothers me?  I really like studying this material, but I think these points that are overlooked are not obviously trivial and could possibly matter.  I think it was you that ingrained in my head the point of continuity with respect to the subspace topology in my question about Lusin's theorem a few weeks ago.  That opened me up to worrying about the domains of these functions and what funny things could happen when two functions don't have the same domain.

Comment: You might like Royden/Fitzpatrick. In the general measure theory portion of that book, they make explicit that in a *complete* measure space, if $f$ is measurable and $\mu(N)=0$, every function of the form $f+g \chi_N$ is measurable. They also point out that completeness is essential; for example, if the convergence hypothesis in LDCT is merely a.e. convergence and the space is not complete, then the integral of the pointwise limit may not even make sense. They use this discussion to justify the slightly informal language that is conventional in measure theory.

Comment: @Ian, perhaps I am misunderstanding your example, but as I'm reading it is misleading.  Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space (not necessarily complete), $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are measurable functions, $g$ is integrable, $|f_{n}| \leq g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere, and $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise $\mu$-a.e.  If $(X,\mathcal{A}_{\mu},\mu)$ is the completion of the original space, then $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ is $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$-measurable and $\int_{X} f_{n} \, d \mu \to \int_{X} f \, d \mu$.  In particular, $\int_{X} f \, d \mu$ "makes sense."

Comment: @fourierwho What example are you talking about? My very last comment? That one is about integration with respect to the measure *on the incomplete space*. Of course you can start with measurable approximants on the incomplete space to pass to the limit which is defined *on the complete space*, but now sense the integrals on the left and right are not *technically* taking place in the same space.

Comment: @Ian, yes, your very last comment.  I'm only objecting because "may not even make sense" sounded to me more like "the limit isn't integrable due to blow ups, $\infty - \infty$, etc," whereas, in fact, the problem is more like a "wrong definition" technicality.  I don't really agree with your "completeness is essential" remark.  I think it's more like, "completeness is natural."  The counterexample you state is easy to get around even if you don't complete the space.  Redefine the limit function to zero on the null set.  However, the completion is more elegant.

Comment: @fourierwho Sure, "completeness is natural" is another way of saying essentially the same thing, but from the point of view of the incomplete space it is wrong to simply "redefine the limit function to be zero on the bad null set". It is not technically correct to think of this as leaving the integral the same, because before this modification the integral simply didn't exist.

Comment: @Ian, my objections to your comments are that they miss the spirit of the theory for technical points that seem to me to mostly be definitional issues.  For example, I'm becoming more and more convinced that the completion should be defined first, and the integral afterward --- on the completion.  In the spirit of the theory, your statement "from the point of view of the incomplete space" is a bit ridiculous because both the measure and the integral don't see the null sets.  They see the complete space.  The incomplete space doesn't really have a "point of view" of its own.

Comment: At any rate, I wouldn't have said anything if it weren't for your "countexample" with the LCDT.  It's just not the right way to think of the issue.  The integrals (numbers) are actually converging in $\mathbb{R}$, and the functions converge for all intents and purposes.  I think the right way to go is simply to state the LCDT on complete measure spaces.  Actually, I would define completions first and then define integrals on complete spaces.  Otherwise, I don't see any interesting "counterexamples" where redefining the function or passing to the completion don't trivialize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two functions, one on the real numbers and one on the irrational numbers; you can say they are equal (or other properties) a.e with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Here is my understanding:
The main idea is that when you are doing integration, the Lebesgue integral will not see the difference of these two functions. The reason for this is because how Lebesgue integral is constructed, it looks at the pre-image $\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = a\}$. Note that this makes perfect sense even if $f$ is only defined on the irrational numbers.

**Edit:** to answer your question, I would suggest you to look at the construction of Lebesgue integral. In your example, the left hand side is perfectly defined. Here is an example, let $f:\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f\equiv 1$, and $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g\equiv 1$;

$$\int_0^1 f d\mu = 1\mu(\{x\in [0,1] : f(x) = 1\}) = 1*\mu(\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]) = 1 = \int_0^1 g d\mu.$$

The first equality above is from the definition of Lebesgue integral for characteristic function $\chi_A$.

**Edit 2:** Define $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f\equiv 1$. Now let us integrate over a more absurd space, $\mathbb{Q}^c$
$$\int_{\mathbb{Q}^c} f d\mu = 1\mu(\{x\in \mathbb{Q}^c : f(x) = 1\}) = 1\mu(\emptyset) = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, but can we really say their Lebesgue integrals over a set $X$ are equal of they are not both defined entirely on $X$?

If $f$ is defined only on $X \setminus N$, but $g$ is defined on $X$, we can't say $\int \limits_{X} f d\mu = \int \limits_{X} g d\mu$ because the integral on the left hand side doesn't make sense.

Comment: I should add $N$ has measure $0$.

Comment: And also that $f = g$ if $x \not \in N$.

Comment: Edit: I will add this in my answer

Comment: My definition is: If $f \geq 0$, $\int \limits_{X} f \text{ d}\mu = \sup_{0 \leq s \leq f} { \{\int \limits_{X} s \text{ d}\mu \mid s \text{ is a simple function} }\}$ and from this definition, we need that $0 \leq s \leq f$ on all of $X$.  So, $\int \limits_{X} f \text{ d}\mu$ doesn't make sense to me if the domain of $f$ is strictly contained in $X$.

Comment: I don't understand the first equality.  What I think should have been written is $\int \limits_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^{c}} f \text{ d}\mu = 1\mu(\{ x \in [0,1] \mid f = 1 \}$.

Comment: We are integrating $f$ over a larger space, and in this space $f$ is not defined at some of the points. There is actually a mistake in your equation, by definition $$\int_{\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1] } f d\mu = 1\mu(\{x\in \mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1] : f(x) = 1\})$$ if we were integrating over this smaller space $\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, but in your equation, you integrated over the whole space, and then defined it to be the value of $f$ over a subset times the measure of the subset, but you completely ignored the complement of that subset. :(

Comment: And the reason for this is because how I constructed $f$, I didn't write "$f\equiv 1$ a.e", I wrote "$f\equiv 1$". I will add another example.

Comment: This is the problem I have with your latest example:  Using the definition of Lebesgue integral, we should have $\int \limits_{\mathbb{Q}^{c}} f \text{ d}\mu = \sup \limits_{0 \leq s \leq f} \{ \int \limits_{\mathbb{Q}^{c}} s \text{ d} \mu \mid s \text{ is a simple function} \}$, and we have no simple functions less than or equal to $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}^{c}$ since it's not defined there, so the integral is not defined.  The way you are integrating it now does not agree with the definition of the integral I was taught, which is why I am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: OK, my 2nd example is not a really good one. In general, when the set of undefined points has measure zero. And you take the $\sup$ of the set $0\leq s\leq f$ a.e.; $s$ is simple.